# Computador or Computadora?

Tags: definiciones

I have noticed on various occassions, that sometimes the word computadora is used, while as well some people use computador or even ordenador.

While I am able to somewhat understand the usage between computadora and ordenador, the usage of computadora and computador does confuse me. Is it a regional thing? Or is there anything more behind it?

I have Heard both forms of the word on Spanish as well as here in Venezuela.

Comment: As you know things in English do not have gender while in Spanish everything has, so when adopting English words into Spanish several regions adopt different gender. _La computadora_ is feminine and _El computador_ is masculine. It is a matter of regional preferences but you can use both and people will understand. BTW In Colombia use _El computador_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it is regional thing: Computador, computadora, ordenador, PC, all are diferents words to say 'computer'.

In Spain it is more common to say 'ordenador', whereas in Latin America 'computadora' or 'computador'. In countries with more English influence you can hear 'PC' often.

Also the techincal background of the person I think can be important: people in the software industry usually say 'array' and not 'arreglo', or 'mouse' and not 'ratón', etc.

Comment: @fedorqui thanks for your edit, I take notes ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Spain use the word ordenador, because put everything in order, Latinameria use computadora beause is an anglisism commimng for computer, this is the difference but you can use as well one or the other one, and better comptador"A" than computaror.
hope this helps you.

Comment: "In Spain use the word ordenador, because put everything in order" mind to explain what does this mean?

Comment: *ordenador* itself is a *galicismo*